# Unknown login noticed in Ubuntu process

Tags: ssh

I noticed these unknown established to my server. I traced the ip to Hongkong /China area. But I am not able to figure out what these connections are.

I have change the root password and already restarted the server but connections such as these popup in few hours. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
sshd    6765     root    3u  IPv4 109602      0t0  TCP cbd.com:22->222.186.56.87:1384 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    6766     sshd    3u  IPv4 109602      0t0  TCP cbd.com:22->222.186.56.87:1384 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Answer (score 0):

They're almost certainly connections that are attempting to "brute force" (guess) passwords.  You should be able to see what they're doing by watching the auth service logs (`/var/log/auth.log` on Debianish machines, `/var/log/secure` on RHEL-derived systems).

Comment: In addition, if you are on a RHEL derived system, refer to tips from CentOS on [hardening OpenSSH](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH).